Entity Framework: Partial Class - New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session
I am facing the following issu in EntityFramework 6.1.3
I have the following function:
   public ActionResult Confirm()
    {
       
        try
        {
            // Log to the DB
            Helpers.LogText("ConfirmPayment", "CONFIRM : " + OrderID);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ErrorLog<Exception>(Method: System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ClassName: GetType().FullName);
        }

        int apiversion = 0;

        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["apiversion"]))
            {
                int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["apiversion"].ToString(), out apiversion);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ErrorLog<Exception>(Method: System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ClassName: GetType().FullName);
        }

        ComInEC context = new ComInEC();
        Order myOrder = new Order();

        //Get Confirm Page Information from Order
        bool allowSuccessfulPaymentDirectly = false;
        bool continueWithSuccessPage = false;
        string NetCommerceID = "";
        int oID;

        if (int.TryParse(OrderID, out oID))
            myOrder = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(OrderID) ? context.Order.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == oID) : null;
        else
            myOrder = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(OrderID) ? context.Order.FirstOrDefault(e => e.OrderCode.ToLower() == OrderID.ToLower() || e.NetCommerceOrderCode.ToLower().Contains(OrderID.ToLower())) : null;



        if (myOrder != null)
        {
            myOrder.Lang = lang;
            myOrder.NumbersOfCheckouts += 1;
            context.SaveChanges(); // Line 1447
    }
        }
        return View();
    }

And I have created a partial class to override DBContext as follows:
public partial class ComInEC : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            // Log only if logging is enabled
            bool enableLogging = false;
            var appConfig = AppConfiguration.Where(x => x.Key == "EnableLogging").FirstOrDefault();
            if (appConfig != null)
            {
                enableLogging = appConfig.Value.AsBool();
            }


            // Try catch here to continue the normal save process, if the logging failed.
            var lstLogs = new List<LoggingAction>();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the error
            ex.ErrorLog<Exception>("SaveChanges", ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : "", "ComInEC Partial", ChangeTracker.Entries());
        }
        int result = base.SaveChanges(); // Line 159
        return result;

    }

    private void AddLogEntry(List<LoggingAction> lstLogs, EntityState state, string entityName, string primaryKeyValue, string loggedUser, string countryCode, string changeStamp, DateTime changeDateTime, string propertyName, string originalValue, string currentValue)
    {
        LoggingAction changeLog = new LoggingAction
        {
            TableName = entityName,
            PrimaryKeyValue = primaryKeyValue,
            FieldName = propertyName,
            OriginalValue = originalValue,
            NewValue = currentValue,
            ChangeDateTime = changeDateTime,
            ChangeStamp = changeStamp,
            LoggedUser = loggedUser,
            CountryCode = countryCode,
            Type = (int)state
        };

        lstLogs.Add(changeLog);
    }
}

When the code reaches:
myOrder.NumbersOfCheckouts += 1;
context.SaveChanges();
An error on context.SaveChanges is thrown:
- New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session
Tracing the stacktrace:
   **at .ComInEC.SaveChanges() in Classes\Partials\ComInEC.cs:line 159


  at MobilePaymentController.Confirm() in \Controllers\MobilePaymentController.cs:line 1447.**

Please note that the error do not happen always, but randomly.
If I remove the partial class, the error does not happen anymore!
What could be the reason?

What is AppConfiguration? And what happens in ErrorLog? Also, why do you (seemingly) only log exceptions and then continue?

Which line is #159?  This error commonly happens if your SaveChanges call tries reading data from the DbContext. (not allowed) If you do want to read/write data from within the DbContext.SaveChanges() then you need to scope a new bounded DbContext for whatever operations you want to happen within the SaveChanges call.

@GertArnold AppConfiguration is loading a Boolean variable from the DB. I am logging the error of the "Audit trail" and then continue the normal flow so I do not stop the save changes to the DB.

Yeah, we need to see what happens, in code. It all interacts. Please [edit] the question to show this code.

@GertArnold I have added the line as a COMMENT. I removed the unneeded code which is actually just variable declarations and if-statements based on a Boolean variables that I am sure it is not entered since the Booleans are of. So I just pasted the relevant code.
